# Why can't I hit Flask app when port 5000 is open for inbound traffic on EC2

Tags: flask, amazon-ec2

I am trying to deploy my Flask app on EC2. Instead of using Beanstalk, I want to deploy it manually. The ultimate goal is to set up wsgi with nginx. Before doing that, I just want to deploy it like what I did on the local dev computer, i.e. start virtualenv, install all the dependencies, and run `python3 application.py`. By default it runs on port 5000.  It works locally at "localhost:5000/api". (`api` is the blueprint url). However, when I do the same on EC2 (ubuntu) instance, it does not work. I put the url "ec2-public-ip:5000/api" in the browser, it says "This page isn't working. [ip] didn't send any data".

`application.py` is the entry point of the app:

```
from myapp.api.factory import create_app

app = create_app(True)

def main():
    app.run(debug=True, threaded=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I set up the security group for this instance which allows inbound traffic from anywhere (0.0.0.0/0) for port 80, 22, 5000

[image]

Why does it not work when accessing from 5000?

Comment: The default host if not specified is `127.0.0.1` it should be `0.0.0.0`. So you'll be having `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')`. I also encourage you to set your debugging mode into False if it is in production.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this

`app.run(host= '0.0.0.0')`

As per docs

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#a-minimal-application

> Externally Visible Server If you run the server you will notice that
>   the server is only accessible from your own computer, not from any
>   other in the network. This is the default because in debugging mode a
>   user of the application can execute arbitrary Python code on your
>   computer.
>
> If you have the debugger disabled or trust the users on your network,
>   you can make the server publicly available simply by adding
>   --host=0.0.0.0 to the command line:
>
> flask run --host=0.0.0.0 This tells your operating system to listen on
>   all public IPs.